# How to keep centered body background image with original size

Tags: html, css

I want to keep centered the body background image with original size. So when I resize the window screen background it keeps its size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.center_bg
{
    background-image: url('{url_of_image}');
    background-position: center center;
}
```

This is all I can give from what I understood from your question. You need to explain your question in detail.

Answer (score -1):

The [background-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) may be of some interest, although some more information (including some actual code) would be helpful.